# What's the difference between "How can ... / How to..."?

Tags: difference

Sorry for this question which may be trivial:

What's the difference between

1. How **can** I translate it into English ?
2. How **to** translate it into English ?

The modal verb "can" expresses the ability to do something; I understand that the subject is missing in the second question, however, I hear/read the structure How to very often from natives as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your example #1 is correct when you want to ask a question.

Example #2 is only a fragment of a question. It should be something like:

> Can you tell me how to translate it into English?

Or it might be a statement:

> I need to know how to translate it into English.

While you might hear #2 spoken as a partial sentence (usually for emphasis), you probably won't see it written that way unless it's part of a dialog where the person is talking to himself or thinking out loud.

Comment: or unless you read question titles on StackExchange sites. It drives me nuts sometimes.

Comment: That's a good point!

Comment: Titles of things are often written in [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese).